# NPM errors after successfully building and deploying rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been working on a rails app using google-maps-4-rails to visualize the bicycle stations. The app worked fine on my local server, but I am getting errors while deploying to Heroku. I tried launching it locally in production environment but it works correctly. I am at loss, and since it is my first venture into front-end, I don't know how to handle this situation.

I've added the nodejs buildpack earlier to solve some other issue, maybe it's causing problems. I also formated the package.json, though I am not entirely sure if it's correct. Earlier problems were connected to yarn not being available on heroku.

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "sample_app",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "yarn": "1.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku"
  ]
}
```

My logs from heroku :

```
: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-04-20T09:54:42.459328+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-20T09:54:42.009377+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-20T09:54:42.009398+00:00 app[web.1]: > sample_app@ start /app
2019-04-20T09:54:42.009399+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server
2019-04-20T09:54:42.009401+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-20T09:54:42.337386+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-04-20T09:54:42.337425+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-04-20T09:54:42.337427+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-04-20T09:54:42.337429+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-20T09:54:42.337431+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/server'
2019-04-20T09:54:42.337433+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-04-20T09:54:42.337434+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-04-20T09:54:42.337436+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
2019-04-20T09:54:42.337438+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-04-20T09:54:42.337439+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-04-20T09:54:42.343303+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-04-20T09:54:42.343921+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-04-20T09:54:42.345414+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! sample_app@ start: `node server`
2019-04-20T09:54:42.345427+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-04-20T09:54:42.349073+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-04-20T09:54:42.349078+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the sample_app@ start script.
2019-04-20T09:54:42.349081+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-04-20T09:54:42.352338+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-20T09:54:42.352554+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-20T09:54:42.353207+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-20T09_54_42_347Z-debug.log
2019-04-20T09:54:42.440910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I am not sure what files may be helpful, please let me know If I can provide any other that would be of assistance

Comment: Error says that it can't find the file. What's the name of the file your server starts from ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! Not sure, how can I check? I followed some online tutorial and then branched out into my own stuff, do you mean the default route?

Comment: What's the command you use to run your server locally

Comment: Simply rails s. For testing purposes I add RAILS_ENV = PRODUCTION, or however it should be written

Comment: in this command what's s ?

Comment: I think it's a shorthand for server? As in "rails server"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku thinks your Rails app is a Nodejs app because there is a package.json file and no Procfile. That package.json file should be completely unnecessary for a Rails app, try removing it.